Why is my electrical panel buzzing?
I hope you can help me identify where this is coming from. First my electrical is all metallic with 2 wires only, and ground via metal conduit.
After some troubleshooting I've found the following:

On a specific breaker there is a buzzing noise when drawing current. I heard it when an iron was plugged in: when iron is heating there is some buzzing in my panel but also (slightly) at the receptacle upstairs
This breaker feeds my basement ceiling lights (LEDs) and also a couple receptacles on the first floor (one being outside). That's what I know for sure
The 1st floor receptacle shows "no ground" with a Klein tester

With a multimeter on the 1st floor outlet I have:
1/ With basement ceiling lights OFF:

P to N: 126Vac
P to Gnd: 86Vac
N to Gnd: 30Vac

2/ With basement ceiling lights ON:

P to N: 125Vac
P to Gnd: 54.2Vac
N to Gnd: 61.3Vac

3/ Outlet on different breaker for comparison:

P to N: 125Vac
P to Gnd: 125Vac
N to Gnd: 0.2Vac

Here is a video of my panel, where it can be heard. When I get closer around 10s that's when you can hear it best, at 13s it stops.
Thank you for your help!


I can't tell from the video, but it is important to make sure all breakers (i.e., especially the "problem" circuit) are correct for the panel. Please upload a picture of the panel labeling (usually inside the panel door) and a picture showing the actual breakers - ideally close enough so that we can confirm the model #/type of the breakers.

Your readings say "P" and "Vdc". Please double-check and confirm that it is really "Hot" (there is no Positive in AC systems) (N = Neutral, not Negative) and most importantly Volts AC, not DC. I find it hard to believe you would get any usable/consistent values if you were actually in a Volts DC measurement mode, but please confirm (and assuming it is AC, edit to correct it).

Good point it is indeed AC not DC...My mistake in the post above, I've fixed it. I've also added a picture with the breaker in question, top of the row on the right side (the 15Amp one). For labeling it doesn't say much unfortunately other than "Basement".

Key on the breakers is that they are all the correct type. All the ones that are visible are clearly Square D HOM.

Either find the broken/bad joint in the conduit, or (might be simpler) add a ground wire in this particular circuit's conduit.
At some point the hot to ground voltage will be correct. If that point is all the way back at the panel, the connection of conduit to panel is not done properly with the paint scraped off or the hardware scraping the paint off. In any case, at some point, the voltage from hot to ground will drop between one section of conduit and another.
Or, easier to look at with power off, the resistance between neutral and conduit ground will rise significantly. The bad joint/connection is between the section with normal voltage hot to conduit ground or resistance (low) neutral to conduit ground, and the section where voltage seems low and resistance to neutral increases.
But running a ground wire connected to each box in this conduit will sort the issue if you don't care to run down where the bad joint is.

I agree I have been also suspecting a bad ground connection at some point in the conduit. The issue is accessibility to the conduit...somewhere in the basement ceiling I guess, but this is giving me some thoughts. Also I didn't think of checking the resistance that's a good idea, thanks!

The buzzing noise you're hearing could be caused by a loose connection or a faulty breaker. When current flows through a loose connection, it can create vibration and buzzing sounds.
The voltage readings you've taken at the receptacles indicate an issue with grounding.
